# Sort array with priority

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array, this array contains unsorted values.

Ex.

```
$Array_Raw=array('KEY_0'=>'550','KEY_1'=>'400','KEY_2'=>'800',
                 'KEY_3'=>'600','KEY_4'=>'450','KEY_5'=>'100');
```

If we sort `$Array_Raw` in ascending order then we have a new array like:

```
array('KEY_5'=>'100','KEY_1'=>'400','KEY_4'=>'450',
      'KEY_0'=>'550','KEY_3'=>'600','KEY_2'=>'800');
```

This can achieved by `asort()` function, but I need it with priority

`$Array_P` contains priority for keys of `$Array_Raw`.

```
$Array_P=array('KEY_0'=>'4','KEY_1'=>'5','KEY_2'=>'1',
                 'KEY_3'=>'6','KEY_4'=>'2','KEY_5'=>'3');
```

`$Priority_Gap` is a variable (INT) that contains priority skip gap.

It could be: `$Priority_Gap = 60;`

This means `$Array_Raw` should be sorted with ascending order with priority for this expected result:

```
$Array_Raw=array('KEY_5'=>'100','KEY_4'=>'450','KEY_1'=>'400',
                 'KEY_0'=>'550','KEY_3'=>'600','KEY_2'=>'800');
```

The reason `KEY_4` is before `KEY_1` is because the value of `KEY_1` + $Priority_Gap > the value of `KEY_4`, and `KEY_4` has a higher priority than `KEY_1`.

However `KEY_0` and `KEY_3` maintain their relative positions because the value of `KEY_0` + `$Priority_Gap` > the value of `KEY_3`, but `KEY_0` has a higher priority so `KEY_0` is always ahead from `KEY_3`.

All values of `$Array_Raw` are dynamic, `$Array_P` is dynamic and `$Priority_Gap` is dynamic. Even the size of `$Array_Raw` is dynamic. Also, the sorting direction may be set to ascending or descending.

I have been trying to do this for 13 days, only achieved dynamic `$Array_Raw`,`$Array_P` & `$Priority_Gap`, but can't find any way for dynamic size for `$Array_Raw` or for dynamic order.

This is my solution but not sorted with Dynamic Size

```
$array_raw = [
    'key_0' => 550,
    'key_1' => 400,
    'key_2' => 800,
    'key_3' => 600
];

$array_p = [
    'key_0' => 2,
    'key_1' => 3,
    'key_2' => 1,
    'key_3' => 4
];

$priority_gap = 500;






function Sort_Array_Asc($ARRAY,$PRIORITY,$GAP)
{


if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[0]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] + $GAP )
{

        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[0]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
        {

                if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[0]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                    {
                        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2]; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[3]; 
                    }
                }


        }
        else
        {
                if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                {       
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2];     
                }
                else
                {
                    if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                    {
                        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2]; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[3]; 
                    }
                }


        }

}
else
{


        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
        {

                if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                    {
                        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2]; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[3]; 
                    }
                }


        }
        else
        {
                if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                {
                        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2]; 
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[3]] + $GAP )
                    {
                        if($ARRAY[$PRIORITY[1]] <= $ARRAY[$PRIORITY[2]] + $GAP )
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[2]; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $VAL_COMP2  = $PRIORITY[3]; 
                    }
                }


        }

}





return $VAL_COMP2;




}







function CompareArrays($ARRAY,$PRIORITYX,$GAP)
{
    $PRIORITY = array();
    asort($PRIORITYX);
    $count = 0;
foreach($PRIORITYX as $key => $value)
{
    $PRIORITY[$count] = $key;
    $count++;
}   
$NEWARRAY = $ARRAY;
$C1 = Sort_Array_Asc($NEWARRAY,$PRIORITY,$GAP);
$NEWARRAY[$C1] = max($NEWARRAY) + ($GAP * 2) + 1;
$C2 = Sort_Array_Asc($NEWARRAY,$PRIORITY,$GAP);
$NEWARRAY[$C2] = max($NEWARRAY) + ($GAP * 2) + 1;
$C3 = Sort_Array_Asc($NEWARRAY,$PRIORITY,$GAP);
$NEWARRAY[$C3] = max($NEWARRAY) + ($GAP * 2) + 1;
$C4 = Sort_Array_Asc($NEWARRAY,$PRIORITY,$GAP);
return array($C1,$C2,$C3,$C4);
}



$SortedArray = CompareArrays($array_raw,$array_p,$priority_gap);



echo "<br><br><br><br><pre>";
print_r($SortedArray);
echo "</pre><br><br><br><br>";
```

Comment: What are all the dots doing in your question? Please format your code with the button for that purpose: `{ }`.

Comment: Why not combine these arrays into an array of objects: `new Priority($value, $priority, $priorityGap)`. And then you can use usort to check all of these conditions in one custom sorting function.

Comment: Another solution to sort Array of priorities and after just take values in right order.

Comment: Question may be good, but unable to understand, because lot of text and the logic is not explained correctly. Can you please post actual inputs and what desired output you want (like real array not this textual format). May be then only some-one can help you. explain logic based on real input values (they need to be proper array not textual representation)

Comment: ...and show your coding attempt

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array_raw = [
    'key_0' => 550,
    'key_1' => 400,
    'key_2' => 800,
    'key_3' => 600,
    'key_4' => 450,
    'key_5' => 100,
];

$array_p = [
    'key_0' => 4,
    'key_1' => 5,
    'key_2' => 1,
    'key_3' => 6,
    'key_4' => 2,
    'key_5' => 3,
];

$priority_gap = 60;

asort($array_raw);

/*
the array is already sorted so i just keep values where $a<$b === 1.
and using Boolean algebra and Karnaugh Map i get :

$a<$b $pa<$pb $a+$pg>$b  $r
  A      B       C      
  1      0       0       -1
  1      0       1       -1
  1      1       0        0
  1      1       1        1

  return -1 when : AB'C' + AB'C = AB' --> $va < $vb && $pa > $pb
  return  1 when : ABC  --> $va < $vb && $pa < $pb && $a + $pg > $b
  return  0 when : ABC' --> $va < $vb && $pa < $pb && $a + $pg < $b
*/  

uksort($array_raw, function($a, $b) use($array_p, $priority_gap, $array_raw) {

    $va = $array_raw[$a];
    $vb = $array_raw[$b];

    $pa = $array_p[$a];
    $pb = $array_p[$b];

    if($va < $vb && $pa < $pb) {
        return -1;
    }

    if($va < $vb && $pa > $pb && $va + $priority_gap > $vb) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_raw);
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [key_5] => 100
    [key_4] => 450
    [key_1] => 400
    [key_0] => 550
    [key_3] => 600
    [key_2] => 800
)
```

Comment: is there any problem with my proposed solution ? @ShubhamPanchal

Comment: yes.. check the output from both functions.. yours and mine

Comment: sir you said : This means $Array_Raw should be sorted with ascending order with priority for this expected result: array('KEY_5'=>'100','KEY_4'=>'450','KEY_1'=>'400',
                 'KEY_0'=>'550','KEY_3'=>'600','KEY_2'=>'800'), this is exactly what i get with my function, the only difference is that i use lowercase naming convention

Comment: change $priority_gap to 500 and then sort with your function and also with mine then see output.. mine function works perfectly but it not support dynamic size of $array_raw

Comment: sir your have missing data in your example, why di you remove KEY_4, KEY_5 ? can you also give us some example for the input and output for the function ?

Comment: what is you're output ? mine is Array
(
    [key_2] => 800
    [key_3] => 600
    [key_0] => 550
    [key_1] => 400
)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151296/discussion-between-shubham-panchal-and-yoeunes).

Comment: sure, my first time in chat